# What is the space complexity of a vector of empty vectors?

Tags: c++, std, space-complexity

Will the space complexity of be O(n) or O(1) considering all the vectors the vector holds is empty?

```
vector<vector<int>> mat(n);
```

Comment: I don't think the standard prohibits the implementation from having empty vectors pre-allocate a block

Comment: I think the standard requires that the default constructor be noexcept, which (in general) precludes allocation.

Comment: @MarshallClow  - It doesn't preclude allocation, but it does shape/constrain what happens if the allocation fails.   Calling `std::abort()` if an allocation fails would, technically, allow a function to be `noexcept`.    Furthermore, a fair few operating systems do lazy allocation - code may request allocation, the system does not actually *do* the allocation,  some subsequent code attempts to use the allocated memory, the system then commits to do the allocation, the allocation fails, and only then an exception may be thrown.   This type of lazy allocation does happen in practice.

Comment: Technically correct, yes, but that's not useful for users of the library.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "space complexity", but I'll give this a try.

A `vector` internally, consists of two parts:

- The "local part" which is what gets allocated on the stack when you declare a local variable of type (say) `vector<int>`. This part is constant size - it doesn't change depending on the number of elements in the vector. In many implementations, this is the size of three pointers + an allocator.
- The "remote part" which lives (usually) on the heap, but is allocated using the allocator. This changes size depending on the capacity of the vector. Not the size, but the capacity (the capacity is always at least as large as the size, but may be larger). An empty vector (capacity == 0) *could* have no "remote part".

So a vector of empty vectors would have the following space usage:

- A local part for the `vector<vector<int>>`
- A remote part that consists of N (where that's the capacity of the vector) "local parts of `vector<int>`.
- Each of the `vector<int>`s could have a remote part (which could be empty).

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

An empty vector is an object that exists and thus takes up storage. The outer vector doesn’t really care what it stores, and the standard requires that a vector stores the elements continuously and that each element is a distinct object.

So, from the point of view of the outer vector, you could replace the inner vector with an `int` and nothing changes much - the vector still holds N elements. If those elements are empty `vector<int>`, they’ll be larger than `int`, but the complexity doesn’t change: N objects exist.

It doesn’t even matter whether the inner vectors allocate or not. That would only add some constant factor to the memory cost, the total cost remains in the same O(N) class.